# Headless browser that support Geolocation

Tags: geolocation, client-side, triangulation, headless-browser

Is there any headless browser that support geolocation?
I know Phantomjs doesn't support that feature.
If no, how programs that uses geolocation (prey project & lockit tight) work?
I'm interested in client-side geolocation using WiFi positioning & triangulation.
Can any moderator create a tag for WiPS (Wi-Fi Positioning System), if it's appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

IP Geolocation using IP address done from server-side works for all headless browsers because it can retrieves user IP address instantly on request.

I do not see any HTML5 or Wifi-based Geolocation yet on headless browsers.

Comment: Yeah, thats what i'm looking for; triangulation using WiFi Positioning cause I'm having issues of external IP Geocoding, so I'm neglecting IP method. Thanks anyway, I'll refine my question.