# Headless HTML5 Geolocation

Tags: linux, html, geolocation

I was wondering if there is any way to get the HTML5 Geolocation system without GUI on a Debian based system?

My plan is to geolocate via HTML5 a computer without any GPS system, so I thought I would send a request with an headless browser to my web server, get the headless browser position (by accepting the prompt somehow) and return it to my server, am I wrong?

I saw phantomjs but apparently it's not working for geolocation.

(Yes, I already saw this [Headless browser that support Geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414200/headless-browser-that-support-geolocation) but I think the answer is outdated and my question is more precise)

Thanks

Comment: If the browser doesn't have a GPS then it will just use a GeoIP service. Why bother using the browser as a middleman?Just GeoIP it yourself.

Comment: Because GeoIP is not accurate at all, just try to compare HTML5 Geolocation and Geolocation by IP and you'll see yourself the difference.

Comment: The difference (presumably due to different databases) is … about 5 minutes walk when I test it on my current location.

Comment: I never reached 5 minutes, and even if I'd have reached that, it's not enough acurate to do what I want.